# how to append class for nicescroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, nicescroll

I am using nicescroll in my application.
    I have dedined like

```
$("#Total").niceScroll({
    cursorwidth: '8px',
    cursorborder: 'none',
    cursorborderradius:'0px',
    cursorcolor:"#39CCDB"
});
```

but I don't want to give the styles as above.
   I want to apply these using a class.For that I have implemented like

```
.scroll {
    cursorwidth: '8px',
    cursorborder: 'none',
    cursorborderradius:'0px',
    cursorcolor:"#39CCDB"
}
```

and

```
var scrollbar =  $("#Total").niceScroll({});
scrollbar.addClass("scroll");
```

but is not working,tell me how to apply stylings with a class for nicescroll.

Comment: I don't think CSS has those properties, those are only paramenters given for the `niceScroll method`

Answer (score 2):

When facing problems of the kind you can print the whole object in inspector and see what you can use (using `console.log(nice)`). So here is my solution

```
var div = niceScroll({ ... });
var nice = div.getNiceScroll();
$(nice)[0].rail.addClass('class-for-vertical');
$(nice)[0].rail.addClass('class-for-horizontal');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't do that but you may try

```
var options = {
    cursorwidth: '8px',
    cursorborder: 'none',
    cursorborderradius:'0px',
    cursorcolor:"#39CCDB"
};
$("#Total").niceScroll(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$("#Total").niceScroll({cursorcolor:"#39CCDB",cursorwidth:"8px",cursorborderradius:"0px",cursorborder: "none"});
```

**[See Docs](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/)**

Comment: I have defined like this only,but I don't want to implement like this

Answer (score 0):

**try below code will work for**

```
var scrollbar =  $("#Total").niceScroll({});
$("#Total").addClass("scroll");

.scroll {
    cursorwidth: '8px',
    cursorborder: 'none',
    cursorborderradius:'0px',
    cursorcolor:"#39CCDB"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
$('.custom_scrollbar').each(function(i){

    // ...

  $(this).niceScroll({ ... });

    // ...

  $('.nicescroll-rails').eq(i).addClass('your_class_name');

    // ...

});
```

CSS:

```
.nicescroll-rails.your_class_name div{
    background-color:red !important; /* for cursorcolor:"red" */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add class with jquery:

```
var $scrollbar =  $(selector).niceScroll({});
$scrollbar.cursor.parent().addClass('nicescroll-cursor-parent');
```